# How to save CDATA value with Inno Setup into XML file?

Tags: xml, xpath, inno-setup, cdata, pascalscript

I need to save a CDATA value into an XML file through Inno Setup.

I search into the `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` document but without success regarding the way to write properly the value into the node.

If I try just to declare `XMLNode.Text := AValue;` with the value I want `ExpandConstant('<string><![CDATA[my value]]></string>);` in my code, the XML interpreter replace all the characters `'<>'` with the XML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

```pascal
function SaveValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AValue : string): string;
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant;  
begin
  Result := '';
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLDocument.setProperty(
        'SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:ns=''urn:mathworks.matlab.settings''');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      XMLNode.Text := AValue;
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);      
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  XMLFile: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (PageId = wpReady) then 
  begin
    XMLFile := ExpandConstant('path to xml file');
    if FileExists(XMLFile) then 
    begin
      SaveValueToXML(
        XMLFile, '//ns:key[@name=''InstallationFolder'']',
        ExpandConstant('&lt;![CDATA[value to write]]&gt;&lt;/string&gt;'));      
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Is there a way to declare CDATA section with `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` with Inno Setup? I tried with the escaped character and it produced the same result also with the `XMLNode := XMLNode.createCDATASection(Avalue);` syntax without success...

XML file contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings name="matlab" visible="true" xmlns="urn:mathworks.matlab.settings" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mathworks.matlab.settings settings.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- ... -->
    <settings name="addons">
        <!-- ... -->
        <key name="InstallationFolder">
            <string></string>
        </key>
    </settings>
</settings>
```

And we need the code to modify XML to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings name="matlab" visible="true" xmlns="urn:mathworks.matlab.settings" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mathworks.matlab.settings settings.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- ... -->
    <settings name="addons">
        <!-- ... -->
        <key name="InstallationFolder">
            <string>
                <value><![CDATA[my value]]></value>
            </string>
        </key>
    </settings>
</settings>
```

final code :

```
const
  NODE_ELEMENT = 1; 

(*Function to load and save value to an XML file*)
function SaveValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AValue : string): string;
var
  XMLNode: Variant;
  XMLNode2: Variant;
  XMLDocument: Variant; 
begin
  Result := '';
  XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  try
    XMLDocument.async := False;
    XMLDocument.load(AFileName);
    if (XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then
      MsgBox('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + 
        XMLDocument.parseError.reason, mbError, MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
      XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:ns=''urn:mathworks.matlab.settings''');
      XMLNode := XMLDocument.selectSingleNode(APath);
      XMLNode2 := XMLDocument.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, 'value', 'urn:mathworks.matlab.settings');
      XMLNode2.appendChild(XMLDocument.createCDATASection(AValue));
      XMLNode.appendChild(XMLNode2);      
      XMLDocument.save(AFileName);     
    end;
  except
    MsgBox('An error occured!' + #13#10 + GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  XMLFile: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if (PageId = wpReady) then 
  begin
    XMLFile := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2018b\matlab.settings');
    if FileExists(XMLFile) then 
    begin
      SaveValueToXML(XMLFile, '//ns:key[@name=''InstallationFolder'']/ns:string', ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\MathWorks\MATLAB Add-Ons'));      
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`createCDATASection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766409(v=vs.85)) is a method of a "document", not a "node".

This works for me:

```pascal
XMLNode.appendChild(XMLDocument.createCDATASection(AValue));
```

---

Whole code, including creation of the `value` node:

```pascal
const
  NODE_ELEMENT = 1;
```

```pascal
XMLNode2 := XMLDocument.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, 'value', 'urn:mathworks.matlab.settings');
XMLNode2.appendChild(XMLDocument.createCDATASection('my value'));
XMLNode.appendChild(XMLNode2);
```

---

Additionally, your XPath needs to select the inner `string` node:

```
//ns:key[@name='InstallationFolder']/ns:string
```

---

Result:

```xml
<key name="InstallationFolder">
    <string>
        <value><![CDATA[my value]]></value></string>
</key>
```

Comment: Great !! it works fine Martin, many thanx again.just i have to find out why it's insert outside the <string> balises...;-)

Comment: tags in english ^^

Comment: My xml file look like this : <key name="InstallationFolder"><string>
   </string></key> and the CDATA should be inserted between the string tags, is anybody knows the syntax to the '//ns:key[@name=''InstallationFolder'']' path to include the tags with ?

Comment: after the setup, the CDATA entry has been insert after the string tags, i want the CDATA inserted between the string tags

Comment: Martin, i cannot modify the xml file as you did. Currently, this is the file containing settings for the MATLAB application. This file contains the syntax that has been posted before and it's similar to xml code. Even if i applied your modification to my code, i still get the issue about xml interpretation. I updated my question with the result. This is why i wanted to use the CDATA instead to avoid this issue with the xml code interpretation.

Comment: The tags for the value is not the one expected <value xmlns=""/> versus <value></value> and we still outside of the <string></string> tags

Comment: i assume the fact the file is not pure xml coding thus the way to implement script is a quite difficult....

Comment: sorry i didn't see your answer regarding the path, my apologies

Comment: I find out the `XMLDocument.createNode` information but i didn't know how to implement in my code, thanx for your patience Martin, it's working perfect. Regarding the CDATA, MATLAB wait for this information in her settings file and even don't start if the entry is not writing as expected. Great support from you ^^